# Setting up a chrooted SFTP user in a directory whose parent has group write permissions

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have a user who only has sftp privileges (no ssh) and who is chrooted in SFTP to `/data/docker`. `/data` (which is a separate drive) has 775 permissions and I'd like to keep it that way. However, when there is group write access to `/data`, I get this error when trying to sftp in as this user:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

How can I permit SFTP without chmodding `/data`to 755?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenSSH [sshd_config](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config) manual is pretty clear about the requirements for the chroot directory:

> ```
>  ChrootDirectory
>          Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after
>          authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-
>          owned directories that are not writable by any other user or
>          group.
> ```

If you want `/data` to be mode 0775, then it can't be part of the path for an SSH chroot folder.

I think the way to work around this with OpenSSH would be to create another path like `/chroot` with the correct permissions. Use a [bind mount](https://fermilinux.fnal.gov/documentation/tips/mount-bind-chroot), NFS, or whatever your OS supports to mount this `/data/docker` folder within the new folder. Then you would set `/chroot/docker` as the chroot folder. Users should be able to access the contents of `/data/docker` through the `/chroot/docker` path.

Alternately, you could build and use your own copy of OpenSSH `sshd` without this restriction. Or you could think about using a different SFTP server. [JScape](http://www.jscape.com/) has a commercial product that would probably do what you want.